# How to remove View in Android?

Tags: android, android-view, layout-inflater, viewgroup, android-inflate

I have two `Buttons` which is in main layout. If Add `Button` is clicked it has to add `EditText` dynamically(Using Inflater). This part is working. If  Remove `Button` is clicked it has to remove those `EditText` with last in first out.But I don't know how to remove views.

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_edit, null);
            ll.addView(view);
        }
    });
    remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ll.removeViewAt(0);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you please check your layout once? It might have another elements also.

Comment: In Main layout I have only two buttons with Linear Layout. In 'add_edit.xml' only EditText without layouts.

Comment: Can you keep a global copy of the newly inflated view ? Then use ll.removeView(view). Instead of by index.

Comment: Tried.. It removes only the last view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use that to remove the last in:

```
ll.removeViewAt(ll.getChildCount() - 1 );
```

alternatively, you can during inflation "remember" the views to remove

```
ArrayList<View> viewList = new ArrayList<View>();

// during inflation
view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_edit, null);
viewList.add(view);
ll.addView(view);

// then to remove the last
view  = list.get(list.size() - 1);
ll.removeView(view);
```

Comment: `ll.removeViewAt(ll.getChildCount() - 1 );` This works but it removes that Button also.. i dont want button to be removed

Comment: so use the second option I gave you. That second option is more reliable, because even if you have other stuff in the layout, it will only remove what was added using the button. Remember to check boundaries on the ArrayList

Comment: Thanks.. `view  = viewList.get(viewList.size() - 1);` This removes only the last view.

Comment: but as I said, don't forget to check boundaries. For example, when size=0 you'll probably have problems.

Comment: Sorry.. I don't know how to check.. Guide me

Comment: `if (viewList.size() > 0) {
     view = viewList.get(viewList.size() - 1);
     ll.removeView(view);
    }` I have tried this already.. its removing only the last view..

Comment: but most importantly, if you don't have any view at all it won't crash your app =]

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Let me explain my issue. I added 4 EditText by clicking Add button 4 times. Now I'm clicking remove button. It removes only the last EditText. Remaining 3 EditText still exist. Is there anyway to remove?

Comment: and you click again and it will remove the next and click again the next. If you want to remove all just make a for loop in the ArrayList